# Using a dot as an argument in

Tags: r, tidyverse

There is something about the use of a dot as an argument that I'm not getting.

Using the starwars dataset that is built into the tidyverse packages.

Using this code:

```
starwars %>% 
    select(height, gender) %>% 
    filter(!complete.cases(.))
```

I get this output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  height gender
   <int> <chr> 
1    167 NA    
2     96 NA    
3     97 NA    
4     NA male  
5     NA male  
6     NA female
7     NA male  
8     NA none  
9     NA female
```

And yet for reasons that I don't understand, I can't get the same output using this code:

```
starwars %>% 
    select(height, gender) %>% 
    filter(is.na(.))
```

Why does the . argument work for complete.case but not for is.na
I've seen a dot being used quite a lot but have never really understood what its doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dot `.` is a placeholder for the entire data.frame in this scenario.
`complete.cases` is a function made specifically to work with data.frames,
looking rows that contains `NA`, and returns a logical vector for `filter` to use.

`is.na` on the other hand works on vectors. In this case, only the first available vector in the piped data.frame has a logical vector returned, which is what `filter` is using the subset the data.frame.

```r
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>% 
  select(height, gender) %>% 
  filter(!complete.cases(.))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   height gender   
#>    <int> <chr>    
#> 1     NA masculine
#> 2    183 <NA>     
#> 3    183 <NA>     
#> 4    178 <NA>     
#> 5     NA masculine
#> 6     NA feminine 
#> 7     NA masculine
#> 8     NA masculine
#> 9     NA <NA>

# only filters on the first column,
# it doesnt know to check any more
# since is.na is meant for vectors, 
# not data.frames
starwars %>% 
  select(height, gender) %>% 
  filter(is.na(.))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   height gender   
#>    <int> <chr>    
#> 1     NA masculine
#> 2     NA masculine
#> 3     NA feminine 
#> 4     NA masculine
#> 5     NA masculine
#> 6     NA <NA>

# same as
starwars %>% 
  select(height, gender) %>% 
  filter(is.na(height))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   height gender   
#>    <int> <chr>    
#> 1     NA masculine
#> 2     NA masculine
#> 3     NA feminine 
#> 4     NA masculine
#> 5     NA masculine
#> 6     NA <NA>

# switching first column changes it
starwars %>% 
  select(gender, height) %>% 
  filter(is.na(.))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   gender height
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 <NA>      183
#> 2 <NA>      183
#> 3 <NA>      178
#> 4 <NA>       NA

# same as
starwars %>% 
  select(gender, height) %>% 
  filter(is.na(gender))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   gender height
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 <NA>      183
#> 2 <NA>      183
#> 3 <NA>      178
#> 4 <NA>       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In this case `.` represents the entire data.frame.

For `filter`, you need a logical vector that is the same length as the data has rows, but instead you're getting a matrix that has the same number of rows but has two columns.

```
is.na(starwars %>% select(height, gender))
#       height gender
# [1,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [2,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [3,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [4,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [5,]  FALSE  FALSE
#... And 82 more rows
```

Remember that the `%>%` operator is also using `.` as the first argument to `filter`. So you could think of this as:

```
filter(starwars %>% select(height, gender), is.na(starwars %>% select(height, gender)))
```

Here's an approach that is similar to yours:

```
starwars %>% 
  select(height, gender) %>%
  filter(Reduce(`|`,as.data.frame(is.na(.))))
## A tibble: 9 x 2
#  height gender   
#   <int> <chr>    
#1     NA masculine
#2    183 NA       
#3    183 NA       
#4    178 NA       
#5     NA masculine
#6     NA feminine 
#7     NA masculine
#8     NA masculine
#9     NA NA
```